# Upgrading DB when using existing Database with Android App

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am using my existing Database with my android contact app. It works fine for the first time. If I upgrade the Asset folder's Database and reinstall the app the Database doesn't upgrade it show the old one during the app run on emulator.

How the `onUpgrade()` method works if I change the DB version on every release of app in case of using existing Database?

Here is my `DataBaseHelper.java`

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    private static String TAG = "DataBaseHelper"; // Tag just for the LogCat window
    //destination path (location) of our database on device
    private static String DB_PATH = "";
    private static String DB_NAME ="SBLdata.db";// Database name
    private static String DATABASE_TABLE ="SBL_Contact";// Database name
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;
    private final Context mContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private int oldVersion;
    private int newVersion;

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context, String dbName)
    {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION );
        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17){
            DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
        }
        else
        {
            DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
        }
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException
    {
        //If database not exists copy it from the assets

        boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase();
        if(!mDataBaseExist)
        {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            this.close();
            try
            {
                //Copy the database from assests
                copyDataBase();
            }
            catch (IOException mIOException)
            {
                throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase");
            }
        }
    }
    //Check that the database exists here: /data/data/your package/databases/Da Name
    private boolean checkDataBase()
    {
        File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        return dbFile.exists();
    }

    //Copy the database from assets
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException
    {
        InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int mLength;
        while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer))>0)
        {
            mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
        }
        mOutput.flush();
        mOutput.close();
        mInput.close();
    }

    //Open the database, so we can query it
    public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException
    {
        String mPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
        return mDataBase != null;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close()
    {
        if(mDataBase != null)
            mDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {}

   @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (oldVersion < DataBaseHelper.DATABASE_VERSION) {
            //drop old table and create and copy the new one
        }else{
            //do Nothing
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: are you using sqliteasset helper?

Answer (score 0):

OnUpgrade is called whenever you increase the version number of your database.

Comment: Please post appropriate answer

Comment: You asked "How the onUpgrade() method works if I change the DB version on every release of app in case of using existing Database?"I read this as when does onUgrade get called?

Comment: If you want to load new data in to your database every time you release a new app version you will need to increment the version number and insert the data in your OnUpgrade statement. Alternatively just create and use a new database with a new name.

Comment: I tried this by changing the version number. could u please help me on  `OnUpgrade()` ?

Comment: I would actually recommend going with the second option above which is to use a new name for your new database. That way when your app starts and tries to use the database with the new name it won't find it and will then call the OnCreate method of your DataBaseHelper class and load in the new database. This is all assuming that you are happy to trust that the new data in your new version is safe.

Comment: your second method create a new DB but keep the existing :(

Comment: It does but you're no longer using it, your DatabaseHelper is now using the new db.

Answer (score 0):

what you do inside onUpgrade() is upto you. you can create a new database or upgrade existing in any way you want. that means you have to manually drop the old table and insert these data into a new table. or use ALTER_TABLE.

Comment: almost all tutorials have DROP table inside `onUpgrade()` you can google for ALTER_TABLE but the db version must be updated to get it called

Comment: Do you know I am using my existing DB instead of create. So The `onUpgrade()` method is working .